# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type Entrada as array

Tags: php, php7

El día de hoy he intentado solucionar este problema, pero no he podido, alguien que me pueda ayudar seria un verdadero placer para mi.

Este es mi código;

```
public static function mostrar_entradas_busqueda($entradas) {
        $count = count($entradas);
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) { 
            if ($i % 3 == 0) {
                ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <?php
                }
                $entradas = $entradas[$i - 1];
                self::mostrar_entrada_busqueda($entradas);

                if ($i % 3 == 0) {
                    ?>
                </div>
                <?php
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: que tipo es $entradas es un arreglo o un objeto?. $entradas = $entradas[$i - 1]; se esta actualizando la variable, lo recomendable seria usar una variable auxiliar

Answer (score 0):

Lo que esta pasando es que el método esta recibiendo un array de objetos.

Intenta averiguar cómo están viniendo los datos con un `var_dump($entradas)` .

Sin saber muy bien cómo llegan los datos, y suponiendo que son un array de objetos puedes usar este código...

```
public static function mostrar_entradas_busqueda($entradas) {

       foreach($entradas as $entrada) {

       echo "<div class='row'>";

         foreach ($entrada as $nombre => $valor){
            echo "Nombre: ".$nombre." Valor= ".valor;
         }

       echo "</div>";

}
```

---

El código lo que hace es recorrer el array de objetos y en cada vuelta recorre el objeto.